# Reference request for a "truncated version" of the de Rham algebra

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Let's start on the $n$-torus for sake of simplicity.$\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb T}$
If I understand the relevant definitions correctly, the usual de Rham algebra of smooth differential forms on $\T^n$ is freely generated as a DGA by the 1-forms $dx_1, \dots, dx_n$, and the top-degree part is generated as a $C^\infty(\T^m)$-module by the $n$-form $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$.

Suppose I now take this DGA but impose the following truncation condition: I fix some $m \leq n$, and then declare that $dx_{i(1)}\wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i(m)}=0$ for any choice of indices $i(1),\dots, i(m)$. Have such objects appeared in the literature and are they standard constructions in homological algebra or differential geometry?

The motivation I have comes from attempts to study what one might view as a Banach-algebraic version of the Kähler module for certain function algebras that contain $C^\infty(\T^n)$ as a continuously included, dense subalgebra; in those settings the analogues of the $n$-forms actually vanish, but the analogues of the $1$-forms don't. So I wondered if the Banach-algebraic version of the de Rham algebra could be viewed as the completion of some well-known algebraic gadget in the appropriate norm, and was hoping that this gadget had already been documented in the literature.

Of course one can ask the same question on any nice compact Riemannian manifold, but I would settle for having a reference which looks at the $\T^n$ case.

Comment: Isn't it a plain quotient?

Comment: @FernandoMuro Probably - if you mean that I've used the wrong terminology. I was thinking in analogy with rings of truncated power series.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong. I think I don't really understand the question. In homological algebra, this kind of quotient is pretty common. It is called truncation in a $t$-structure. In this case you're considering the canonical $t$-structure in a derived category and you're truncating not a plain complex but an algebra object.

Comment: Let me try to explain the context of my question. As I understand it: in usual algebra, there are certain truncations/quotients which are named and studied, perhaps because they are useful tools or have geometric interpretations. E.g. the algebra of dual numbers. I was hoping that the quotient/truncation mentioned in my question was known to people in a similar way. It seems like some kind of model for "mildly singular" but not in the sense of alg-geom (e.g. Gorenstein etc)

Comment: The top cohomology group would be $\Omega^{m-1}(\mathbb T^n)/\mathrm{im}d$. Similar groups occur naturally when studying Chern-Weil theory, differential characters, and similar stuff. For example, Chern-Simons classes take values there. Maybe there is a relation?

Comment: Also in differential K-theory and more general differential cohomology theories.

Comment: In Hodge theory one often considers the "dual" truncation to the one you describe (although on the holomorphic de Rham complex), setting all forms *below* a certain degree to zero. This is what gives rise to the Frölicher spectral sequence, and the Hodge filtration on the cohomology of a compact Kähler manifold.